# External React components are not rendering in App.js

Tags: reactjs

I am very new to react.js. When I was working on a practice project, I encountered this strange error. Some components from an external js file render when imported and some do not.

app.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Hello from './components/hello'
import functionalClick from './components/fuctionalClick'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">

        <Hello name='Lol   '></Hello>

        <functionalClick></functionalClick>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

functionalClick.js:

```
import React from 'react'

function fuctionalClick() {
    return (
        <div>
            <button>Click</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default fuctionalClick
```

hello.js:

```
import React from 'react';
const Hello = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>
                Hello {props.name}!
            </h1>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Hello;
```

The functionalClick.js does not render But the first method does(hello.js).
Even when the syntax i followed, was almost same.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqLT0.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might have a typo in the declaration of the function `fuctionalClick`. Looks like you're missing an `n` after the `c`. Your Component might be imported as `undefined`. Check your browser console for other info.

Try changing this:

```
import functionalClick from './components/fuctionalClick'
```

and this:

```
<functionalClick></functionalClick>
```

To this:

```
import fuctionalClick from './components/fuctionalClick'
```

and this:

```
<fuctionalClick></fuctionalClick>
```

And see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks! Stupid me. Also with that, the component name, being imported, should always start with a capital letter. Thanks again.

Comment: You're not stupid. This stuff can be complicated. You're doing great! Keep it up.

Answer (score 2):

As per the docs 
[User-Defined Components Must Be Capitalized](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized)

React also shows some warnings when you try to use not HTML tags in lowercase.

Warning:  is using uppercase HTML. Always use lowercase HTML tags in React.

Warning: The tag  is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter.

Check the warnings here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-exw9h

Answer (score 1):

In your question typo mistakes but sometimes also not work then check your components name first later. if it is small then do it capital.

Comment: It's helpful in your answer to list what/where the typo is for the OP as well as citing any capitalization requirements the OP should change in their code.